# How to conditionally render page depending on express/mssql middle ware feedback

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have made a full stack application with a register activity successfully adding to db. 
How would I conditionally render the home page dependent on if the login is correct.

In my login route I have an if statement which successfully logs "bad creds" if do not exist or "login: login successful.." if it does.

I added a redirect into the handle submit(this is triggered once the login form button is pressed) which was supposed to be triggered if successful (it technically is but it determines "bad creds successful as well").

I have attempted an if stametn but I am not sure how to use this with express middle ware.

the logic I would want the the portion of handle submit to do is something along the lines of

```
if (login successful){
window.location.href = "/home";

}

else {
window.location.href = "/login";
(preferably with a alert )
}
```

Login route

```
app.post("/login", async (req, response) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    var request = new sql.Request();
    var Email = req.body.email;
    var Password = req.body.password;

    console.log({ Email, Password });

    request.input("Email", sql.VarChar, Email);
    request.input("Password", sql.VarChar, Password);

    var queryString =
      "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";

      //"SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE email = @Email AND Password = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password + 'skrrt')";

    const result = await request.query(queryString);

    if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      console.info("/login: login successful..");
      console.log(req.body);
      req.session.loggedin = true;
      req.session.email = Email;
      response.send("User logined");
    } else {
      console.info("/login: bad creds");
      response.status(400).send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    response.status(500).send("Check api console.log for the error");
  }
});
```

```
 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.email.length < 8 || this.state.password.length < 8) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
    } else {
      const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

      fetch("/login", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        // .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);

          // if ( ) {
          //   console.log("nice");
          // } else {
          //   console.log("not nice");
          // }
          // window.location.href = "/home";
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have explained in the first place that you had a React app in the frontend. Talking at the same time about Express middleware and login route is a bit messy. :)

What you're doing is a login/sign in process through an API. This means your server should return JSON information regarding the login outcome. Then, your frontend should handle that in whatever way you want to. This means that your server should simply treat the login request as any other data request. Return a status code and some optional JSON data.

Authentication is a BIG subject and since you did't provide many details, I can only tell you how normally the overall process should go:

1. Send the user credentials to the server (like you do in your POST request)
2. Handle the response received from the server. If login was successful, you should receive some information from the server, like the user id, email, session id, either in the response JSON data or by HTTP headers. You should keep this information in the frontend, normally in localStorage, and use it for every request to the server to provide your identity. You should look up JSON Web Tokens.
3. In your React app, you want to check when starting the application if the user is already logged in or not (using the piece of information mentioned in step 2, or trying to fetch and endpoint that returns user information like `/me`). If you don't have that information or the request fails, redirect to Login.
4. In your React app, in your login page, handle the fetch result and redirect to home if the user is authenticated, or stay there and display whatever info you want.

I assume that since you're using user login some resources should be protected from being accessed by non logged in users or restricted depending on the logged in user. This is done with middleware on your Express server, that should check the user id / token / session id information your React app should be sending with every request.

To redirect using React Router, you don't want to use `window.location`. You want to use the Router itself to avoid reloading the full page. You can either use the injected `history` prop on your Login route component or wrap any component that needs it with `withRouter` HOC.

This article seem to lay out all options using React Router pretty well:
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/redirect-on-login-and-logout.html

Hope this helps, this is a complex subject that you should split into smaller problems and tackle one at a time. ;)

Comment: Hi I initially tried that but it didn't work for me. It would fall into the if statement but would not redirect.

Comment: I have just added that into my server.js and it sitll does nothing

Comment: Hi coderStew, perhaps I didn't get your question. Do you want a REST API-like login process, with a Single Page Application as the frontend, or are you rendering your UI from express views? I edited my code to end the response after redirect.

In any case, you have so many mixed concerns in the code that is hard to know what could possibly go wrong. Why don't try a simple redirect in a route, and once you got it, use it in your login?

Comment: im using react-router with my front end and my routes just dispalys sql data to these pages. All i want is a basic logic for a usable if stamen t within my handle submit.

Comment: Edited my response after your comment, hope it helps!